# Замена mysql, tr cтрочки с уникальным текстом

Tags: php, mysql

Есть около 2000 записей, часть содержимого:

```
BLA-BLA<tr><td>Product code</td><td>CXXX</td></tr><tr class="info" bgcolor=#F3F3F3><td>Original Part Number</td><td>BLA-BLA
```

Надо убрать вот это эту часть:

```
<tr><td>Product code</td><td>CXXX</td></tr>
```

Вместо `XXX` - уникакальное значение на каждую запись

Пробовал вот такой запрос:

```
$vendorrefenrceremovefi =  mysql_query("
UPDATE ps_product_lang 
SET description = REPLACE
(description,  '<tr><td>Product code</td><td>C%</td></tr><tr class=\"info\" bgcolor=#F3F3F3><td>Original Part Number',  
'<tr class=\"info\" bgcolor=#F3F3F3><td>Original Part Number' );
"  ,$db) or die(mysql_error()) ;
```

Ошибок нет, эффекта нет.

Что посоветуйте?

Comment: бэкслэши перед двойными кавычками действительно присутствуют в базе данных? если нет, то и в запросе их быть не должно.

Answer (score 1):

Вы пытаетесь использовать регулярные выражения, но `replace` в `mysql` их не поддерживает.

Можно написать собственную функцию (см., например [ответы на этот вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986826/how-to-do-a-regular-expression-replace-in-mysql)).

Но если у вас не `mysql`, а `mariadb` (актуально для многих современных дистрибутивов `gnu/linux`), то там есть функция [REGEXP_REPLACE](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/regexp_replace/).

Answer (score 0):

с помощью locate и substr вырезаете нужную часть.

используйте from-подзапрос или множественный update, чтобы обойти ограничение на выборку из обновляемой таблицы